# Iterate on remaining elements inside every forEach iteration

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am looking for an efficient (in the sense of short code) way to implement this. I am iterating using forEach an array of arrays, and in every step of the forEach loop I need to count the elements existing in the remaining iterations of the forEach, to get those arrays count each element and save that count. See the code below.

This is the initial array of arrays I have:

```
const blocks = [ 
  ['A','B','C'],
  ['A','B','C'],
  ['A','B','D','E'],
  ['A','B','D','E'],
  ['A','B','F','G'],
  ['A','B','F','G'],
  ['A','B','F','H','I'],
    ]
```

The desired output would be this (One of these arrays in each iteration):

```
[
  [
    {block: 'A', duration: 7},
    {block: 'B', duration: 7},
    {block: 'C', duration: 2}
  ],
  [
    {block: 'A', duration: 6},
    {block: 'B', duration: 6},
    {block: 'C', duration: 1}
  ],
  [
    {block: 'A', duration: 5},
    {block: 'B', duration: 5},
    {block: 'D', duration: 2},
    {block: 'E', duration: 2},
  ],
  [
    {block: 'A', duration: 4},
    {block: 'B', duration: 3},
    {block: 'D', duration: 1},
    {block: 'E', duration: 1},
  ],
  [
    {block: 'A', duration: 3},
    {block: 'B', duration: 3},
    {block: 'F', duration: 3},
    {block: 'G', duration: 2},
  ],
  [
    {block: 'A', duration: 2},
    {block: 'B', duration: 2},
    {block: 'F', duration: 2},
    {block: 'G', duration: 1},
  ],
  [
    {block: 'A', duration: 1},
    {block: 'B', duration: 1},
    {block: 'F', duration: 1},
    {block: 'H', duration: 1},
    {block: 'I', duration: 1},
  ]
 ]
```

---

**My solution for now**:

Thanks to the solutions provided below (in particular by FFire), which worked perfectly for the example provided, I was able to fabricate something that worked for me. The key was to have access to **index** and **arr** in the iteration and then use **arr.slice(index)**.

I reiterate the question here as my use-case was a bit different than initially stated in my example. Sorry about that.

In a case like this:

```
const blocks = [
  ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  ['B', 'D', 'E'],
  ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E'],
  ['A', 'B', 'F', 'G'],
  ['A', 'B', 'F', 'G'],
  ['A', 'B', 'F', 'H', 'I']
];
```

I needed to count two separated groups of 'A', A 2 and A 4 ...

Therefore my current solution (based on previous answers) is as follows:

```
const blocks = [
  ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  ['B', 'D', 'E'],
  ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E'],
  ['A', 'B', 'F', 'G'],
  ['A', 'B', 'F', 'G'],
  ['A', 'B', 'F', 'H', 'I']
];

let results = []
let lastLetters = []
blocks.forEach((block, index, arr) => {
  let letters = block
  // Discard letters already in results
  const newLetters = block.filter(letter => !lastLetters.includes(letter))
  // Asign lastLetters for next Iteration
  lastLetters = letters
  // Initialize letters counts lengths
  let letterLengths = newLetters.map(letter => ({ block: letter, duration: 0 }))
  // Initialize letters that remain
  let lettersThatRemain = newLetters
  arr.slice(index).forEach(block =>{
    const blockLetters = block
    // Get only letters that remain from previous iteration
    lettersThatRemain = blockLetters.filter(letter => lettersThatRemain.includes(letter))
    // Increase count for those letters that remain
    lettersThatRemain.forEach(letterR => letterLengths.find(letterL => letterL.block === letterR).duration += 1)
  })
  console.log(letterLengths)
})
```

Still cumbersome but works, any improvement in its implementation is obviously welcome.

Comment: Please may you share your efforts so far?

Comment: I run a forEach loop on blocks, but I am stuck at trying to iterate over the "remaining" elements of the array in each iteration ... is that even possible?

Comment: Please post the code that you have attempted so that we can check and help you

Comment: What if the fourth row of the input was `['A','B','C','D','E'],`, what would you expect the output to be? Or is that not input that would occur?

Comment: I think for your current code to work (assuming I've understood the problem), you would need to remove `.filter(letter => !lastLetters.includes(letter))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const blocks = [
  ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E'],
  ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E'],
  ['A', 'B', 'F', 'G'],
  ['A', 'B', 'F', 'G'],
  ['A', 'B', 'F', 'H', 'I']
];

// Reduce right, because its easier to go from the last array and then increment a number of element occurrence
const reduced = blocks.reduceRight((acc, item) => {

  // In 'result' we will store the result array and in the 'map' we will store number of occurrence of an element
  const {result, map} = acc;

  const mapped = item.map(item => {

    // If there is not an occurrence yet, then its a first occurrence and we set it to 1
    const occurrence = map[item] || 1;

    // Increment occurrence for the next iteration
    map[item] = occurrence + 1;

    return {block: item, duration: occurrence}

  });

  // Put it on the start of an array (because we are going from the last element to the first because of reduceRight)
  result.unshift(mapped)

  return acc;

}, {result: [], map: {}});

const finalResult = reduced.result;
```

Comment: Please donot answer to a question where the user have not attempted anything or have not mentioned any difficulty he is facing. This can be achieved by a loop logic, but seems the user have not even attempted anything to achieve this.

Comment: What if the user is such a noob that he does not have any attempt to show that gets even close to a solution, and still was not able to find any stackoverflow question/answer addressing his issue. Should he be directed to another website for noobs? The question should not be answered? BTW thanks to all those other that didn't follow this advice.

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple:

1. First you flatten the array and maintain a counter for each
   character
2. Second map the output using the above map

```js
function arrayCharCounter(inputArray) {
  const flatArr = inputArray.flat();
  // Maintain a char counter map using above flattened array
  const counterMap = flatArr.reduce((accum, current) => {
    accum[current.toString()] = accum.hasOwnProperty(current.toString())
      ? accum[current.toString()] + 1
      : 1;
    return accum;
  }, {});

  // Use the counter map to produce desired output
  const outputArr = inputArray.map((arr) => {
    return arr.map((item) => ({
      block: item,
      duration: counterMap[item.toString()]--,
    }));
  });
  return outputArr;
}

// Run example
console.log(
  arrayCharCounter([
    ["A", "B", "C"],
    ["A", "B", "C"],
    ["A", "B", "D", "E"],
    ["A", "B", "D", "E"],
    ["A", "B", "F", "G"],
    ["A", "B", "F", "G"],
    ["A", "B", "F", "H", "I"],
  ])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const blocks = [['A','B','C'],['A','B','C'],['A','B','D','E'],['A','B','D','E'],['A','B','F','G'],['A','B','F','G'],['A','B','F','H','I'],];

const remain = (blocks) => blocks.map((block, index, arr) => 
  block.map((letter) => {
    const duration = arr.slice(index)
      .filter((block) => block.includes(letter))
      .length;
    return { block: letter,  duration };
  })
);
    
console.log(remain(blocks));
// [
//   [
//     { block: 'A', duration: 7 },
//     { block: 'B', duration: 7 },
//     { block: 'C', duration: 2 }
//   ],
//   [
//     { block: 'A', duration: 6 },
//     { block: 'B', duration: 6 },
//     { block: 'C', duration: 1 }
//   ],
//   [
//     { block: 'A', duration: 5 },
//     { block: 'B', duration: 5 },
//     { block: 'D', duration: 2 },
//     { block: 'E', duration: 2 }
//   ],
//   [
//     { block: 'A', duration: 4 },
//     { block: 'B', duration: 4 },
//     { block: 'D', duration: 1 },
//     { block: 'E', duration: 1 }
//   ],
//   [
//     { block: 'A', duration: 3 },
//     { block: 'B', duration: 3 },
//     { block: 'F', duration: 3 },
//     { block: 'G', duration: 2 }
//   ],
//   [
//     { block: 'A', duration: 2 },
//     { block: 'B', duration: 2 },
//     { block: 'F', duration: 2 },
//     { block: 'G', duration: 1 }
//   ],
//   [
//     { block: 'A', duration: 1 },
//     { block: 'B', duration: 1 },
//     { block: 'F', duration: 1 },
//     { block: 'H', duration: 1 },
//     { block: 'I', duration: 1 }
//   ]
// ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It works like a charm for the example provided. Unfortunately I forgot in my example that in my particular use-case I need to differenciate wether the letter is repeated continuously or not, as separated counts. So if a letter stops appearing and appears again later, it should be a different count.

Comment: FFire thanks to your input I was able to get a solution, and I updated the question with my current implementation according to a slightly different usecase than the example I provided in my initial question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how good of an explanation this is but...

This uses reduceRight, like @munleashed's answer, to go backwards through the array. Each iteration of reduceRight will produce an object that looks something like `{ A: 2, B: 2, F: 2, G: 1}` and add it into the accumulating array at the same index as the blocks array. To get the value of the duration of the current object it can look at the previous iteration's object and add 1 to that value (or 0 if there wasn't a value in the previous iteration).

The `map()` at the end takes these object and converts them into arrays of block-duration objects.

```js
const blocks = [
  ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  ['B', 'D', 'E'],
  ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E'],
  ['A', 'B', 'F', 'G'],
  ['A', 'B', 'F', 'G'],
  ['A', 'B', 'F', 'H', 'I']
];

const res = blocks.reduceRight(
  (acc, row, i) =>
    Object.assign(acc, {
      [i]: row.reduce(
        (row_map, letter) => Object.assign(row_map, {
          [letter]: (acc[i + 1]?.[letter] ?? 0) + 1
        }),
        {}
      )
    }),
  []
).map(
  (row) => Object.entries(row).map(
    ([block, duration]) => ({ block, duration })
  )
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want count remaining the apply the following formula

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

array.forEach(function(single, i) {
  console.log(array.length -i -1);
});
```

Comment: How exactly does this count the remaining elements?

Comment: which elements ?